# Need Correct Sql Stmt

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql

I have Sql Data Base every Thing Work Right

```
  NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS where (modifiedAdress) VALUES (\"%@\")", hemaInsert];
```

i use this for insert but how i but condition

only i Need Sql Statement That Said Insert into contact column modifiedAdress Value hemainsert `(condition hemaInsert = ID )`

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS where (modifiedAdress) VALUES (\"%@\")", hemaInsert];
```

Comment: It is a very bad practice to use string formats to create SQL statements. Bad things can happen if the replacement value has certain characters. This can lead to queries that fail. This is also the basis of many SQL injection hacks. See the answer from iPatel for the proper approach of binding values into the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to Insert an entire row/tuple/record.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS where modifiedAdress is '%@'", hemaInsert];//you can go for " or ' as per oracle or other sqls.


NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS where modifiedAdress = \"%@\"", hemaInsert];//you can go for " or ' as per oracle or other sqls.
```

EDIT:

INSERT is used to add a tuple(row). If you want to insert only at a particular column you need to use **UPDATE**.

The syntax is :

```
UPDATE tableName
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Use:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE CONTACTS SET modifiedAdress  = \"%@\"", hemaInsert];
```

Comment: i need to inser into specific column (modifiedAdress) while Condition (hema = ID ) into Table Contact

Comment: Insert inserts a tuple(row). If you want to insert only at a particular column you need to use UPDATE.

Comment: how can i use it in this situtation

Comment: It update all the rows in modifiedAdress Column,,, ineed to update only specific row , the row with id = hemainsert

Comment: See the syntax, if you not give the where clause, it will update all. If you want to restrict then use WHERE="your required conditions"

Comment: i do                                                                  NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE CONTACTS WHERE ID =\"%@\" SET modifiedAdress  = \"%@\"", hemaInsert,hemaInsert];

Comment: UPDATE CONTACTS SET modifiedAdress = \"%@\" WHERE ID = \"%@\"", hemaInsert, hemaInsert]

Comment: and what is hemalInsert even for modifiedAdress and also for id ?

Comment: thank You it work Can i get your mail because i can't use stack over flow chat

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) InserRecorinTable:(NSString*) hemaInsert
{


        int ret;
        const char *sql =   "insert into CONTACTS (modifiedAdress) values (?);";

        sqlite3_stmt *insStmt = NULL;
        if ( !insStmt )
            if ( (ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &insStmt, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK ) {}

        // bind values
        sqlite3_bind_text(insStmt, 1, hemaInsert, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                

        if ((ret = sqlite3_step(insStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {NSLog(@"error while inserting marker");}
        sqlite3_reset(insStmt);


}
```

Comment: +1 for not using string formats and instead for properly using `sqlite3_bind_xxx`.

Comment: However, you should take the time to update your answer to use the query and variables used by the OP.